# Showing that $f$ is Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\lbrace \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\rbrace \subset [a,b]$ and $f(x):[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in \lbrace \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\rbrace , \\ 0 & \text{for the rest}\end{cases}$$

I wanna show that $f(x)$ is integrable without using the notion of measure zero.

And I'm using two definitions of integrability (assuming that $f(x)$ is bounded) :

$1) \forall \epsilon >0$, exists a partition $P$ of $[a.b]$ such that $U(f:P)-L(f:P)<\epsilon$

$2) \forall \epsilon >0$ exists partitions $P,Q$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f:Q)-L(f:P)<\epsilon$

My problem is to found a partition since I don't know how 
 $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are distribuited on $[a,b]$. I also tought about get two partitions, one for the points $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ and another for the rest...

Thanks!

Comment: If you have seen that integrals are additive yet in your course, I would follow Salahamam's hint below.  Otherwise consider the partition where you surround each point $a_i$ by $\left( \alpha_i - \frac{\varepsilon}{2n}, \alpha_i + \frac{\varepsilon}{2n}\right)$.  In other words, consider the partition $\mathcal P = \{a, \alpha_1 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2n}, \alpha_1 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2n}, \alpha_2 - \frac{\varepsilon}{2n}, \alpha_2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2n} \dots , b \}$.  You may have to consider as a separate case if either $\alpha_1 = a$ or $\alpha_n = b$.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

You just need to prove that $f $ is integrable at $[\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1}] $ and then use additivity.
for this consider the subdivision
$$\sigma_i=\{\alpha_i, \alpha_i+\frac {\epsilon}{2},\alpha_{i+1}-\frac {\epsilon}{2},\alpha_{i+1}\} $$

and observe that
$$U (f,\sigma_i)=\epsilon $$
$$L (f,\sigma_i)=0.$$

Comment: I unterstood that I can prove that $f(x)$ is integrable in  each interval $[\alpha_i,\alpha_{i+1}]$ but I did not unterstand why this argument it's enough to show  that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Comment: @R.MCM additivity ensures that $\int_a^b=\int_a^c+\int_c^b $.